# Problema para ejecutar proyecto web en tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Buen dia amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando levantar un aplicación, es decir, ejecutarlo pero por alguna razón no me aparece la opción ejecutar mediante el servidor tomcat a pesar de lo tengo instalado ya que tengo otros proyectos que si los reconoce, me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se deberá que no aparezca la opción del servidor de aplicaciones web? Hay alguna forma de configurarlo? El proyecto está basado en maven

Comment: Tienes que añadir/configurar un servidor Tomcat en el IDE y asociar el proyecto al mismo: Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments

Comment: Hola, ya se encuentra añadido pero sigue sin reconocerlo.

Comment: Ahora tienes que añadir el proyecto al servidor y ejecutar el servidor

Comment: Hola, ya volví a hacer lo de Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments, de ahí ya no aparece algo adicional y solo está Apply and close, lo de añadir el proyecto al servidor en que parte es?

Comment: Tienes que tener una pestaña (subventana?) llamada servers, es ahí donde lo añades. Suele estar debajo de la del editor si estás con la "vista" J2EE. No tengo eclipse instalado aquí, pero mira esta guía: https://www.theserverside.com/video/How-to-test-and-deploy-WARs-with-Tomcat-and-Eclipse

Comment: Si, ya hice toda esa configuración de la parte server, de ahí que mas seguiría o que otras configuraciones se hacen?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141087/discussion-between-cratus666jose-and-pablo-lozano).